# Proving a set of vectors is independent

Tags: linear-algebra, independence, gaussian-elimination

[image: set of vectors, S]

Firstly, my apologies for attaching the question as an image. I was having a lot of problems typing it in MathJax.
The question asks to show S is independent. From my understanding, I have to prove that:
$$
\alpha{\begin{pmatrix}
 1\\
 1\\
 0\\
 \end{pmatrix}} +\beta{\begin{pmatrix}
 1\\
 0\\
 1\\
 \end{pmatrix}}= {\begin{pmatrix}
 0\\
 0\\
 0\\
 \end{pmatrix}}
$$if and only if $\alpha$ =$\beta$ = 0. I try to solve this using an augmented matrix, and reduce it to row-echelon form.
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1&1&0\\
      1&0&0\\
      0&1&0
    \end{array}
\right] $$ $\underrightarrow{R2+R3}$
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1&1&0\\
      1&1&0\\
      0&1&0
    \end{array}
\right] $$ $\underrightarrow{R3-R2}$
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1&1&0\\
      1&1&0\\
      0&0&0
    \end{array}
\right] $$ But, 
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      0&0&0\\
    \end{array}
\right] $$ means that the system has infinitely many solutions. Therefore, $\alpha,\beta$ could have infinitely many solutions, and so the set $S$ is dependent.
But the solution says that the set is independent because $\alpha,\beta = 0$. Could someone please assist me by pointing out where I have gone wrong? I would appreciate if you could stick to my method of solving (proving $\alpha,\beta=0$) because this is how I would like to approach it)

Comment: The matrix after $R3-R2$ is wrong. How did you get zeros in the bottom row? What you should have done in your row reduction is first move the bottom two rows to the top, and then eliminate the $1$'s in the new last row. (But you do not need to do any row reduction in any case.)

Comment: Your process for finding a row-echelon form isn't correct. You have to make row operations so as to obtain columns with all coefficients (except the pivot) equal to zero. For example, your 1st operation should be $R_2\to R_2-R_1$.

Comment: But, shouldn't the zero's be at the bottom in row-echelon form?

Answer (score 2):

From
$$
\alpha{\begin{pmatrix}
 1\\
 1\\
 0\\
 \end{pmatrix}} +\beta{\begin{pmatrix}
 1\\
 0\\
 1\\
 \end{pmatrix}}= {\begin{pmatrix}
 0\\
 0\\
 0\\
 \end{pmatrix}}$$

If you consider the third coordinate, you directly get $\beta=0$.

Comment: And looking at the 2nd coordinate...

Comment: Yes, but I need to prove that $0$ is the ONLY solution of $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: @abruzzi26 this is the case here. We show that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ must be equal to $0$, so this is the unique solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\alpha \left(\begin{matrix}1\\1\\0\end{matrix}\right)+\beta \left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right)= \left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right)\\\implies\begin{cases}\alpha \times 1+\beta\times 1=0\\\\\alpha \times 1+\beta\times 0=0\\\\\alpha \times 0+\beta\times 1=0\end{cases}\\\implies \alpha =\beta=0$$